# sql join without some lines

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I want to join the  **tableA** with the **same tableA** using *group_id=group_id* in condition of the type on the table_type is different  
tableA

```
    id  name    type_id group_id
--------------------------------
    1   name1   4   2   
    2   name2   3   1
    3   name3   3   2
    4   name4   3   3
    5   name5   4   3
```

type table:

```
id  code
------------
3   out
4   in
```

**I want to get the return as :**

```
    id  name    type_id group_id    bro_id  bro_name
---------------------------------------------------------
    2   name2   3   1       1   name1
    3   name3   3   2   
    4   name4   3   3       5   name5
```

I tried the sql:

```
SELECT tA.id,tA.name,tt.code,tAi.id AS "bro_id",tAi.name AS "bro_name",tti.code
FROM tablea tA 
INNER JOIN table_type tt ON (tA.type_id=tt.id and tt.code='OUT')
LEFT JOIN tablea tAi ON (tA.group_id=tAi.group_id and tA.id!=tAi.id ) 
INNER JOIN table_type tti  ON (tti.id=tAi.type_id and tti.code='IN')
```

but I can't get the line:

```
3   name3   3   2   null    null
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the bro_id field in your desired results?

Comment: bro_id is the brother of the line with the same group_id

Comment: @DanBracuk the logic behind the bro_id to know if the type = IN  exist or not

Comment: What's the point in differentiating between `in`, `out` codes, since this is not reflected on the output?

Comment: FYI, you have an error in desired output, name2 has no brother. name3 has a brother: name1.

Comment: I forgot to rename my req in the examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your left join's ON statement to the bottom of the query:

```
SELECT tA.id,tA.name,spt.code,tAi.id AS "bro_id",tAi.name AS "bro_name",tti.code,tA.date
FROM tableA tA 
INNER join table_type tt on (tA.type_id=tt.id and tt.code='out')
LEFT join tableA tAi -- <---on statement removed
INNER join table_type tti  on (tti.id=tAi.type_id and tti.code='in')
    on (sp.group_id=spi.group_id and sp.id!=spi.id ) -- <--- moved to here
```

Your last INNER JOIN was basically limiting the query to only items where the tAi existed. This is because you're joining tti directly to tA and tt, whereas you want the LEFT JOIN to join two subqueries each of two tables.

You can do the other suggested answer of LEFT JOINing both the last two tables but it's not really ideal, and occasionally wrong (I think it would be fine in this case however).

Comment: This is a valid and I think better response than mine. [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/00f54/6](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/00f54/6) Upvoted!

Comment: any documentation about this case of moving ON statement ?

Comment: Interesting point @m3asmi. I've had a look and struggled to find anything on it actually. As I mentioned I think of a left join as joining subqueries rather than just joining a table.

Answer (score 1):

You have used a Inner join to lookup for type of the brother.
It should be also a left join:

```
LEFT join table_type tti  on (tti.id=tAi.type_id and tti.code='in')
```

[SQLDFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/00f54/5)

Comment: can't get the line :s

Comment: This can't be. The query `select * FROM tableA tA 
INNER join table_type tt on (tA.type_id=tt.id and tt.code='out')` is giving you 3 lines?

Comment: if you add only left joins to the upper query, you won't loose any rows :)